# Selecting MAX on column then MAX from column that is dependent on first value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, max

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    ParentID int,
    DateCreated DATETIME,
    ItemNo int
)

INSERT INTO #Test(ParentID, DateCreated, ItemNo) VALUES  (1,'2008-10-01 00:00:00.000',0)
INSERT INTO #Test(ParentID, DateCreated, ItemNo) VALUES  (1,'2008-10-01 00:00:00.000',1)
INSERT INTO #Test(ParentID, DateCreated, ItemNo) VALUES  (1,'2008-05-01 00:00:00.000',2)
INSERT INTO #Test(ParentID, DateCreated, ItemNo) VALUES  (1,'2008-05-01 00:00:00.000',3)

INSERT INTO #Test(ParentID, DateCreated, ItemNo) VALUES  (2,'2008-06-01 00:00:00.000',3)
INSERT INTO #Test(ParentID, DateCreated, ItemNo) VALUES  (2,'2008-06-01 00:00:00.000',4)
INSERT INTO #Test(ParentID, DateCreated, ItemNo) VALUES  (2,'2008-04-01 00:00:00.000',6)
INSERT INTO #Test(ParentID, DateCreated, ItemNo) VALUES  (2,'2008-04-01 00:00:00.000',8)
```

I need a way of selecting highest DateCreated with highest ItemNo on same parentID, and if it is possible to use solution in query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Test t
  JOIN
  (
    If I could get maximum row here somehow that would be great
  ) maxt
  ON t.ParentID = maxt.ParentID 
  JOIN SomeOtherTable sot
  ON sot.DateCreated = maxt.MaxDateCreated
  AND sot.ItemNo = maxt.MaxItemNo
GROUP BY
  sot.Something
```

Just to clarify what results should look like:

```
ParentID        DateCreated           ItemNo   ParentID      MaxDateCreated    MaxItemNo
  1,       '2008-10-01 00:00:00.000'  ,0         1,      '2008-10-01 00:00:00.000',1
  1,       '2008-10-01 00:00:00.000'  ,1         1,      '2008-10-01 00:00:00.000',1
  1,       '2008-05-01 00:00:00.000'  ,2         1,      '2008-10-01 00:00:00.000',1
  1,       '2008-05-01 00:00:00.000'  ,3         1,      '2008-10-01 00:00:00.000',1
  2,       '2008-06-01 00:00:00.000'  ,3         2,      '2008-06-01 00:00:00.000',4
  2,       '2008-06-01 00:00:00.000'  ,4         2,      '2008-06-01 00:00:00.000',4
  2,       '2008-04-01 00:00:00.000'  ,6         2,      '2008-06-01 00:00:00.000',4
  2,       '2008-04-01 00:00:00.000'  ,8         2,      '2008-06-01 00:00:00.000',4
```

Comment: What is the MaxItemNo, and why is it not 3 and 8 instead of 1 and 4 ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk MaxItemNo is Maximum ItemNo Where the date is maximum on same paren, combination that I need for parent 1 would be '2008-10-01 00:00:00.000',1 because that is maximum ItemNo in maximum DateCreated of ParentID with 1

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Because I need highest combination of DateCreated and ItemNo given that DateCreated has  first priority, so '2008-10-01 00:00:00.000'  ,1 > '2008-05-01 00:00:00.000'  ,3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the Maximum of DateCreated and the Maximum ItemNo for this DateCreated:

```
select ParentId,
       DateCreated as MaxDateCreated,
       ItemNo as MaxItemNo
     from 
      (select PArentID,DateCreated,ItemNo, 
         Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID 
                             ORDER BY DateCreated DESC, 
                                      ItemNo Desc) as RN
         from #Test          
      ) t3
     where RN=1
```

[SQLFillde demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/911af/3)

UPD

And to get results as mentioned in the question you should join this with #TEST like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test t
  JOIN
  (
select ParentId,
           DateCreated as MaxDateCreated,
           ItemNo as MaxItemNo
         from 
          (select PArentID,DateCreated,ItemNo, 
             Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID 
                                 ORDER BY DateCreated DESC, 
                                          ItemNo Desc) as RN
             from test          
          ) t3
         where RN=1
  ) maxt
  ON t.ParentID = maxt.ParentID
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/911af/4)

Comment: I only see 2 rows in the result

Comment: @t-clausen.dk To get desired result you should JOIN this table with #Test on ParentId. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
DateCreated, ItemNo, ParentID,
MAX(DateCreated) over (PARTITION BY ParentID)  MaxDateCreated, 
MAX(itemNo*case when rn = 1 then 1 end) over (PARTITION BY parentid) MaxItemNo
FROM
(
  SELECT DateCreated, ItemNo, ParentID, 
  row_number() over (PARTITION BY parentid order by DateCreated desc, ItemNo desc) rn 
  FROM #test
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution: Using `max(concat(first_column,second_column))`

The idea is concat two column then sort it using max.

Example: `select max(concat(first_column,second_column)) from table`